# .NET MemberShip Update Problem

Tags: asp.net-membership

I am having problems updating the MembershipUser.IsApproved field. I have the following code in the POST view of my content page.

```
MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser( id );

if (approved)
     membershipUser.IsApproved = true;
else
    membershipUser.IsApproved = false;
if (!lockedOut)
    membershipUser.UnlockUser();

Membership.UpdateUser( membershipUser );
```

approved and lockedOut are passed in as parameters to the POST view.

If I set a breakpoint and follow the code through, when approved = true, it follows the correct path and sets membershipUser.IsApproved to true. However, when I look at the IsApproved parameter in membershipUser that is being passed to Membership.UpdateUser, it is still set to false, which is the value it had when the content page was first displayed.

I am obviously doing something wrong, but I can't see what it is. Can anybody throw any light on it?

Comment: I think that semantically it should be `if (lockedOut) membershipUser.UnlockUser();`

Comment: @Rus Cam - It's not that property I'm having problem with. Although it may seem funny. it is in fact coded correctly.

Comment: The underlying code might be correct, but the semantic meaning of that code isn't - `If not locked out, unlock the user` :) What MembershipProvider are you using?

Comment: @Rus Cam - I am using AspNetSqlMembershipProvider. It is of type System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that

```
membershipUser.UnlockUser();
```

also sets

```
membershipUser.IsApproved = false;
```

Therefore, I need to unlock the User before I set

> IsApproved
>   .